Unable to access user id through guard after login in laravel
I have this route defined in web.php

web.php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
        Route::get('login', [FrontendController::class ,'showLoginForm'])->name('user.login-show');
        Route::post('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@login')->name('login.post');
}

this is my login controller
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Auth;
    use App\User;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Darryldecode\Cart\Facades\Cart;
    
    
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        use AuthenticatesUsers;
        //
        protected $redirectTo = '/user/dashboard';
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest:web')->except('logout');
        }
    
        public function showLoginForm()
        { 
            return view('pages.login');
        }
    
        public function login(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'email'   => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required|min:6',
                'remember_me'=>'nullable'
            ]);
            $request->merge(['user_type'=>'0']);
            if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt([
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,'user_type' => $request->user_type
            ], $request->input('remember_me'))) {
                $userID = Auth::guard('web')->user()->id;
                return redirect()->intended(route('web.dashboard'));
            }
            else{
                return back()->withErrors(['message'=>'Username or Password is Invalid'])->withInput($request->all());
            }
        }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
         
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {

    }
}


config/auth.php

 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],


RedirectedIfAuthenticated Middleware:

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}


Admin Login Controller:

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    //
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
   
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'remember_me'=>'nullable'
    ]);
    $request->merge(['user_type'=>'1']);
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,'user_type' => $request->user_type
    ], $request->input('remember_me'))) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    else{
        return back()->withErrors(['message'=>'Username or Password is Invalid'])->withInput($request->all());
    }
   
    }
 

public function logout(Request $request)
    {
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}

if I try to log in I'm then in login controller able to get user id through this code able to get user id using this code Auth::guard('web')->user()->id; but after this login function code is executed then not able to get user id in other methods or controller, it returns Attempt to read property "id" on null because user is null & i'm able to access login page even if i'm logged in. I have two guards, one for admin another one for user
Any solution to fix this login issue

I'm not certain. Try these In the handle()
Change
$guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

to
$guards = empty($guards) ? ['web'] : $guards;
# Setting the default to 'web' if no guard is specified


if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/home'); # Change this to your post login (after login) redirect
}


At last
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear


Thanks i updated this code in RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware but if i'm logged in then again trying to hit this login url http://localhost:8000/user/login able to view login form again but it should redirect to /user/dashboard, i have two guard for admin this is working if i access http://localhost:8000/admin/login again it is redirecting to http://localhost:8000/user/dashboard

set /user/dashboard when you successfully log in. not same login page

i was trying to change to this code  foreach ($guards as $guard) {             if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {                 if($guard=="admin")    {                     return redirect('/admin/dashboard');                 }                 else  {                     return redirect('/user/dashboard');                 }             }         } this also did not work, i have added admin login controller in code above can you pls check, for admin it is working

If you want to retrieve the currently authenticated user according to Laravel Doc :
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Retrieve the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();

// Retrieve the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();


Thanks for the answer but getting null value in Auth::user();, is there any issue with login code can you pls check the above code

In that case there is something that is not correct in the login code, try to remove this part 'user_type' => $request->user_type to see if it will work

After a successful authentication attempt you should be regenerating the user session.
if (
  Auth::guard('web')->attempt([
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => $request->password,
      'user_type' => $request->user_type
  ], $request->input('remember_me'))
) {
    $userID = Auth::guard('web')->user()->id;
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return redirect()->intended(route('web.dashboard'));
}

for more information check the docs on manually authenticating users https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication#authenticating-users
